# namespace scope for BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT

Tags: c++, boost

I was going through this document on BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT and I failed to understand the point about this macro used in namespace scope in header files.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

```
namespace my_conditions {

   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits >= 32);
   BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(WCHAR_MIN >= 0);

} // namespace my_conditions
```

The document says that since the header file could be included multiple times, there can be multiple declarations of the macro and some compilers can result in an error.

Multiple inclusions of the namespace my_conditions would not result in an error ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises if you do something like this

**Header1.h**

```
namespace my_conditions {

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(std::numeric_limits<int>::digits >= 32);

}
```

**Header2.h**

```
namespace my_conditions {

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(WCHAR_MIN >= 0);

}
```

since the implementation uses a stub name combined with `__LINE__` to define the typedef when `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` is used at namespace scope. When used at the *same line in the same namespace,* duplicate typedefs will occur, which can result in a compilation error.